# after 1.35.0 update: gLiveView Luck and Ideal showing "--"

Tags: cardano-cli, cardano-node, stake-pool

Hi new stake pool operator here. I'm having an issue after upgrading to 1.35.0. In gLiveView it shows blanks for both luck and ideal and it hasn't minted any new blocks since upgrading.

Any thoughts or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is the tip at 100%? you can check it with `cardano-cli query tip --mainnet/--testnet-magic 1097911063`, if it is not, the node isn't in sync.

From there you can start to troubleshoot, if the BP isn't syncing, means that it doesn't have connection to relays. If it has not that, you need to check that everything is fine on that side, services are up, ports are open, ecc

Another thing that you can check on BP (or on nodes with the flag tracemempool active in the config file), is if those nodes are processing txs or not (gLiveView -> Pending TXs).

You can also check the logs to see if there are any errors with the command `journalctl --unit cardano-node.service --follow`.

Also share the tests that you already have done and the pool ticker, this way we can help you better.

Comment: Thanks Nic_T2C. I’ve ended up downgrading back to 1.34.1 but your suggestions are helpful as the nodes are still syncing. It was hard to find any clear indication that 1.35.0 was stable and ready for mainnet. Do you happen to know what the recommendation is?

Comment: We are currently running 1.35.1 on Testnet and probably 1.35.2 will come.
I am still running 1.34.1 on Mainnet and from what I am concerned, this is the recommended version.
If you are interested, I can share the link to SPO Announcements Telegram Group, this way you can stay always up to date :-)

Comment: That would be great @Nik_T2H

Comment: @Nik_T2K Ok so the producer and two relays are running. Producer gliveview shows 2 outgoing connections. Relays both show pending TXs.


Running`cardano-cli query tip --mainnet` produces the error `query tip  Error: Error while looking up environment variable: CARDANO_NODE_SOCKET_PATH"` which seems significant.

It looks like maybe cnode.sh is not exporting that variable? Using cntools by the way. The producer has created a socket file `node0.socket` in the default cntools location on startup.

Comment: I confirmed the tip is at 100% and all three nodes have values for Pending Tx @Nik_T2K

Comment: That is a good sign, do you still have other thing to solve?

Comment: Hi yes there was still the outstanding problem of gLiveView showing blanks for ideal and luck but I believe I just solved it. I had to manually upgrade CNCLI to v5.0.4. It seems there was an issue running cncli.sh on startup and the cntools prereqs did not install the latest version. Thank you for all of your help!

Comment: This issue was helpful [CNCLI Leaderlog Issue Since 1.35](https://forum.cardano.org/t/cncli-leaderlog-issue-since-1-35/104344/3)

Answer (score 2):

Here is the [SPO Announcement Group](https://t.me/SPOannouncements) and the [Best Practice Group](https://t.me/CardanoStakePoolWorkgroup).
In the second one you can also ask question related to a stake pool and receive help.

About CNtools, I don't have much experience, I personally run without that.
So maybe someone else can step in.

First of all, you need to make sure that your node is running, socket file is created once node is started, so this is one thing that you can check.

Second thing that I thought, is that the problem could come by the fact that the path to the socket isn't defined anywhere.
Without cntools, you create an env variable in .bashrc file as follow:

```
export CARDANO_NODE_SOCKET_PATH=<path_to_socket>
```

But I am not sure if cntools do that automatically.
Try to look on that direction and check if there is a place where you can edit that path to the correct one.

If you find the answer please post it down here. Could be usefull for others and could make me learn something new :-)

Comment: The guild tools (CNTools/gLV/etc) does it automatically, but does not export it to bashrc (as there may be more than one node running on a host, and could result in naughty outcomes).

Comment: Nice, thanks for sharing, so basically he should only add few things to the .bashrc file and he would be good to go? @RdLrT

Comment: To use it on terminal , yip